# Only Identified systems

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

Hello I am making a small online stock management system using php, but the thing is i want that web app to work, on only certain systems which i will define.
The systems which are under my control, and so that other people who comes to know the username and password of my stock management system are not able to use it from other machines until that machine has my permission.

I don't wanna make it on IP thing , because similar IP 's can have more than one machine, and so if that machine is not identified by me, my web app should not work on it.

Please guide how can I do this?

Comment: Have you tried anything...?

Comment: If you're going to use HTTP, IP is the only reliable thing you get. Anything else you have to configure at a router (again ip/mac).

Comment: then can you guide how can I make that type of protection level, that the web app opens on certain specified machines.
I need this because my web app has 3 levels : admin, manager, and sales person
Hence even if the sales person leaks the user name and password, the protected areas do not get visible to others.
Home can be view able.

Comment: @AM26 **If you know** that a password is leaked, then you can disable the account. You also can expire all php sessions as well (this depends on the implementation file storage or database for storing session data). Instead of trying to control where the app is being accessed from, I think you should rely on authentication. There are some options out there to use certificates as part of the authentication, but it's the chicken and the egg problem all over, plus only IE supports it in windows, and you don't get much compatibility with it, unless you write your own java plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Especially the variable 'REMOTE_ADDR'.